# Propagate palette between two QDialogs

Tags: qt4, pyqt4

I have two `QDialog` classes, DialogA and DialogB. DialogA uses a custom palette. It contains an instance of DialogB and opens it upon the user pushing a button. What is the right way to propagate the palette from DialogA to DialogB? I am doing the following:

```
class DialogA(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DialogA, self).__init__(parent)
        # Palette setup in this class
        ...
        DialogB = DialogB(self)

class DialogB(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DialogB, self).__init__(parent)
        if parent != None:
            self.setPalette(parent.pallete())
```

Is there a better way than checking `if parent != None`? I am being picky and prefer not to have an if statement perform this logic. If I call DialogB on its own, `parent == None` so I can't call `parent.pallete()`.

Comment: You must use signal and slots, as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689053/how-to-communicate-or-switch-between-two-windows-in-pyqt4.

Comment: I don't see how signals and slots helps setting the palette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add a parameter to the constructor of `DialogB`?

```
class DialogA(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(DialogA, self).__init__(parent)
        # Palette setup in this class
        ...
        DialogB = DialogB(self, palette)

class DialogB(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, palette, parent=None):
        super(DialogB, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setPalette(palette)
```

Comment: I can do that too, but I would default it to None, leaving a similar situation as the `if` statement with parent. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing some convention that everyone uses.

Comment: As long as you are attempting to call methods on an argument defaulted to `None`, you will either have to perform some kind of check like you are doing, or enclose the affected code in a try/except block.